# How to show the grid in figure when we use `axes0` function?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am use `axes0` function in the https://jp.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54326-axes0.

If I add `grid on;` the grid on figure does not appear.

How to show the grid in figure when we use `axes0` function?

```
clear all;
clc;
gbr1=ezplot('x^2-y-0.2=0',[-1.5 1.5 -1.5 1.5]);
set(gbr1,'color','r','linewidth',2);
hold on;
gbr2=ezplot('y^2-x-0.3=0',[-1.5 1.5 -1.5 1.5]);
set(gbr2,'color','r','linewidth',2);
grid on;
axis equal;
title('');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y','rotation',0);
axes0('origin','topright');
```

[image]

Comment: Is it feasible to substitute something like `set(gca,'XAxisLocation','origin','YAxisLocation','origin')` for the `axes0` call in your code?

Comment: If I use your code, the axis is box and can't same like my figure above.

Comment: Is that the only problem? If so, you could use `set(gca,'XAxisLocation','origin', 'YAxisLocation','origin', 'TickDir','both', 'TickLength',[0.015 0.0375], 'Box','off')`.

Comment: Error using matlab.graphics.axis.Axes/set
While setting the 'XAxisLocation' property of Axes:
'origin' is not a valid value. Use one of these values: 'bottom' | 'top'.

Error in grafikdgnsumbu (line 16)
set(gca,'XAxisLocation','origin', 'YAxisLocation','origin', 'TickDir','both', 'TickLength',[0.015 0.0375], 'Box','off')

I get the error. 
I use MATLAB R2014b.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry then. I didn't realize you were using a pre-R2015b release.